# How to revert a merge which used strategy=ours?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I'm working with a repository where a merge was performed weeks ago which we just discovered used the `--strategy=ours` flag (it was supposed to use the --strategy-option=ours flag), thus not applying any changes to HEAD. However, we need to have the changes applied. Git already recognizes the branch as being merged and the commits in the history of the branch.

This sort of merge can't be reverted using `git revert -m ...`

What would be the proper way of reverting and/or re-applying the merge to change the files?

```
master  A - B - E - F - G ---> L - M - N
             \     /
topic         C - D
```

Merge commit `(F)` would be the culprit in this scenario.

Comment: Is it safe to say you don't want to rewrite history, just produce a new commit on the tip of the branch that merges in the files?

Comment: Actually, rewriting history would be a decent option. For this situation, it wouldn't matter as long as the changes are actually applied. Something to note: We're trying to correct a merge into branch 'master', master has been branched dozens of times, so the history must be able to propagate in a merge to other branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have discovered a solution to this problem. It was all in the letter that Linus wrote regarding reverting faulty merges: [How to revert a faulty merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).
The `git merge --strategy=ours topic` in our case was not intended. Even though it's a faulty merge, it can't be reverted, and having long been pushed, has the same effect of having a revert merge commit without being able to revert the revert commit.

The solution was to checkout the topic branch, run `rebase --no-ff` from the first commit and then merge that branch back into master.

```
git checkout topic
git rebase -i --no-ff <C>
git checkout master
git merge topic
```

This had the effect of yielding:

```
fixed–topic   C'–––D'––––––––––––––––––––-
             /                            \
master  A–––B–––E–––F–––G –––> L–––M–––N–––F2
             \     /
topic         C–––D
```

To really understand this in-depth, read the last portion of the letter [How to Revert a Faulty Merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) using the `--no-ff` rebase option to re-create the branch.

Answer (score 4):

@Highway of Life has a great answer. The one thing is that the rebased commits now look like new different commits, which in many cases may be undesirable. I wanted to merge the identical commits a second time, but `git-merge` prevents this. However, I find time and again that it is always possible to get git to do what you want.

1. Follow Highway of Life's instructions but don't merge straight onto master:

   ```
   git checkout -b fixed-topic <D>
   git rebase -i --no-ff <B>
   git checkout -b re-merged master
   git merge fixed-topic
   ```

   This results in:

   ```
   re-merged               ––––––––––––––––––––------R
                          /                         /
   fixed–topic      C'–––D'                        /
                   /                              /
   master     A–––B–––E–––F–––G –––> L–––M–––N–––F2
                   \     /
   topic            C–––D
   ```
2. Now the tree is set up exactly how you want—all the files show exactly the contents you desire. The one problem is that your merge commit's parents are rebased copies of your original commits, instead of actually being the original commits themselves. It's easy to fix this with [`git-reparent`](https://github.com/MarkLodato/git-reparent):

   ```
   git reparent -p master -p <D>
   ```

   This ends up with:

   ```
   master     A–––B–––E–––F–––G –––> L–––M–––N–––F2
                   \     /                        \
   topic            C–––D                          \
                         \                          \
   re-merged              ---------------------------R
   ```

   An important thing to note is that the contents of R haven't changed since the last step—only the parents.
3. Fast-forward master to the new merge commit:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge re-merged
   ```
4. Finally you can clean up with

   ```
   git branch -d fixed-topic re-master
   ```

Done! Now your history looks like this, with one branch merged twice:

```
master  A–––B–––E–––F–––G –––> L–––M–––N–––F2---R
             \     /                           /
topic         C–––D----------------------------
```

Comment: I didn't know that the `reparent` option is a third party function. Seams a very good solution but I was looking for the simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

a merge strategy that says "keep what you have here no matter what you're merging in" by it's nature cannot be reversed. Checkout the 1st parent of the merge in a new branch, then do the merge again. Rebase --onto the rest of the commits you have on top of your original merge onto this one.

UPDATE:

In your case, if you don't care about the past, you can rebase G-N onto E and then just merge D onto this new master. The rebase will be trivial because F was an --ours merge.

Comment: BTW, I've edited my question to be slightly clearer. -- There have been 69 commits made to the master branch since this merge was performed. I'm concerned about rewriting the history in this case which could cause potentially catastrophic failure for repositories of members of the team and merging their merge of the rebase back into my repos could get interesting. Perhaps if there are no decent alternatives, going the patch route may be the safest way to go?

Comment: rebase and patch is the same thing in the end. rebase is much more automated though. remember to turn your rerere on in case you have to restart and you don't want to do the same conflict resolutions again.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a

`git reset --hard commitHashBeforeMerge`

then

`git push -f`